# Use of Work.com skills in a Customer Community?

Tags: customer-community, work.com

It seems that Work.com skills can be used without a specific Work.com licence (https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workcom_impl_feature_overview.htm&language=en_US).

Can I use them, so that I'll be able to decide alone who is skilled in what, so that Customer Community users will be able to see these skills, but not to endorse or to recommend them?

In this case, can these skills be associated with the topics of my Customer Community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you successfully implemented Work.com  features in your org you can set up permission sets or profiles for the users in your org to have different level of access to the Work.com features.

Comment: Thanks. Can these skills be associated with the topics of my Customer Community?

Comment: Could you explain with a bit more details what do you you mean by associated  and what are those topics you refer to?

Comment: My Community is organized around topics. I want that, for each topic, skilled people appear (people who are specifically skilled in this topic).